# Opencv haartraining

Tags: opencv

What is the difference between real adaboost Logit boost discrete adaboost and gentle adaboost in train cascade parameter..

```
-bt <{DAB, RAB, LB, GAB(default)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html#fht98)

> ```
> boost_type – Type of the boosting algorithm. 
> Possible values are:
> CvBoost::DISCRETE Discrete AdaBoost. 
> CvBoost::REAL Real AdaBoost. It is a technique that utilizes confidence-rated predictions and works well with categorical data. 
> CvBoost::LOGIT LogitBoost. It can produce good regression fits. 
> CvBoost::GENTLE Gentle AdaBoost. It puts less weight on outlier data points and for that reason is often good with regression data. 
> Gentle AdaBoost and Real AdaBoost are often the preferable choices.
> ```